# What layer 4 protocols have port numbers?

Tags: tcp, udp, port, protocols

What layer 4 protocols (specifically, the ones that have a protocol number [registered with IANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers)) use port numbers?

I know TCP, UDP, SCTP (Stream Control Transmission Protocol), and DCCP (Datagram Congestion Control Protocol) have them, but do others exist? An example of a layer 4 protocol that does not use port numbers is ICMP.

Comment: One that I was missing was UDP-Lite. Technically, another one that was missing was Multipath TCP, but Multipath TCP does not have a separate protocol number from standard TCP

Comment: A few more protocols are: RDP, NETBLT, PGM Reliable Transport Protocol. A few protocols with a single port are: HMP, IRTP